# TypeScript : Find and update an element in a nested Json structure

Tags: json, typescript

I have a nested json structure and i want to find an element based on the id so i can access and change his quantity:

```
[
  {
    'title': "title 12"
    'id' : 12
    'level' : 1
    'quantity' : 3
        'childrens': [
                {
                'title': "title 121"
                'id' : 121
                'quantity' : 5
                'level' : 2 
                'childrens':[
                    {
                        'title': "title 1211"
                        'id' : 1211
                        'quantity' : 8
                        'level' : 3
                        ...
```

Let's say i want to update the quantity for the id 1211 and give 12 instead of 8.
To access the id 1211 manually, i can do this

```
this.booksArray.find(x => x.childrens[0].childrens[0].id == 1211).children[0].children[0].quantity= 12
```

But how to do it automaticly ? Which means that if my id is at level 3, look the childrens 2 levels down, if my level is 4, look the childrens 3 levels down and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple recursive function:

```
function setValue(item: any, id: string, quantity: number){
  if (item.id === id) {
    item.quantity = quantity;
  } 
  else if (item.children) {
    item.children.forEach(child => setValue(child, id, quantity));
  }
}
```

This should get you going.

Comment: It doesnt work. For id = 12 (first level) i had to do if(item[0].id === id) to make it work. As for id = 1211, i have to play with the index, but im stuck. I will try to find a way to do it